# Could someone help get this question on track please?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, asking-questions

The question is https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329657/how-to-model-a-simple-economic-market

It seems that the first version was seemingly too broad so I'm doing my best to make it more focused and answerable.

It is about making a domain model and I don't usually have a problem analysing a situation but economics is not obvious to me and I'd probably miss the most important factors at play.

I shouldn't have used to word simulation as that probably implied to those reading that I wanted to make something complex and realistic.

That isn't the case and the aim is a simple educational tool with parameters to toy around with that can be built upon.

So open to all suggestions to get this back on the rails. TIA :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your question is more about economics and economic systems rather than software development. It seems like to answer your questions, the person would need some level of detailed knowledge on the domain. There may be someone here with that knowledge, but this is a community of software developers.

You may want to take a step back and think about what questions you need answered to understand your domain. The first step would be to search common sources - visit Wikipedia or use your favorite search engine. There are also some economics-related Stack Exchange sites, like [Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/), and [Cross Validated (Statistics)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to read their Help Centers and/or Meta before posting, to understand what kinds of questions they find acceptable.

Once you understand your domain, you can come with specific questions about turning a domain concept into something that can be represented in software. But we can't explain your domain to you.

Comment: That is a sensible answer and my first reflex should have been to ask a question on an economics Q&A :)

Comment: @JamesP. Once you do learn what kind of system you are attempting to model, then you can edit your question (or make a new one) to describe in detail the type of system you want, and perhaps get help with object model design or algorithms. But until we know the parameters of the system you are looking to build, most of us probably cannot help you :)